# mysql LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE merges lines

Tags: mysql

I am using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE syntax to load csv files from file on server into db. It works, problem is, some lines are merged together like if there isn't any new line separator. But when I check the specific lines where is the problem, I see there IS the separator in the file. What could be the problem?

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'words.tsv' 
INTO TABLE `words` 
CHARACTER SET `utf8mb4` 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'  ENCLOSED BY '"'  
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(id, lang, text);
```

Data are like ID, lang, text, separated by \t (as the file is named tsv).

If i try only \r as new line separator, it imports only 1 row, if \r\n also only 1 row. if \n multiple rows but some wrong. File is utf8, and i use:

```
SET NAMES utfmb4;
```

Before running the import to suport also Emojis. I dont know if it is related.

```
123 eng Hello world
124 eng Bla bla bla
```

It imports some rows like:

```
id: 123
text: eng Hello world 124 eng Bla bla bla
```

Comment: Could you show the exact lines that get concatenated when imported like this? Is this a deterministic behavior?

Comment: @raina77ow i found the problem thx

Answer (score -1):

So i see problem is the specific lines contained '"' and the command contained part

```
ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

but the lines in reality wasn't enclosed by " so I had to remove this part from the command and it works.